# Synology - mount a directory via sshfs with user/group mapping

Tags: macos, permissions, mount, synology, sshfs

I have been experimenting with `sshfs` with the intent to access a directory on a Synology box and mount it via Terminal. To this end, I am using version of SSHFS as provided by the [FUSE for macOS](https://osxfuse.github.io) project.
The setup is following:

- the directory on the Synology box `/volume1/justnfs` which is to be mounted is owned by `user1:users` with user id 1026 and group id 100 and contains directories/files owned by this user only.
- on my laptop, the user (also `user1`) mounting the directory has user id 501 and group id 20 (group name `staff`)

Now, if I do

```
sshfs -o sshfs_debug syno:/justnfs ./storage
```

the directory gets mounted, nevertheless the user id/group id of all files is not remapped (as expected). To address this, I created two files with the required mapping, namely `users.txt` with `user1:1026` and `groups.txt` with `staff:100`. Then the command

```
sshfs -o sshfs_debug -o idmap=file -o uidfile=users.txt -o gidfile=groups.txt syno:/justnfs ./storage
```

also mounts the remote directory, however, if I then switch to `storage` and do `ls`, the output is completely empty and `dmesg` shows

```
osxfuse: fuse_vnop_readdir failed (err=1)
```

Strangely enough, when I try to `cat` a file with known path (i.e., access it directly), the command succeeds and displays the content of the file. It's as if only the listing of directories was for some reason not allowed.

Interestingly, if I supply the uid/gid explicitly as

```
sshfs -o sshfs_debug -o uid=501 -o gid=20 syno:/justnfs ./storage
```

then `ls` works again.

What could be the reason that the last two commands behave differently and/or that it is not possible to list the content of the directory?